# Remote Debugging Chrome Beta on Samsung Note

Tags: android, google-chrome, adb, remote-debugging, samsung-mobile

My chrome://inspect has been set up. I am able to remote debug other Android devices such as Samsung Galaxy Tab, Nexus 7, Nexus 7 2, and several mobile phones.

I've also gone ahead and updated Samsung's Kies software on my Mac.

I've also tried using `adb` CLI to `kill-server` and `start-server` again. The device is definitely detected.

However, I still can't remote debug and inspect Chrome Beta on the Samsung Note. The device shows up, and the tabs show up in the inspector list. When I click the link to inspect, I get a new window with nothing in it. If I wait, nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug with that particular version of Chrome. It was fixed in a later release.